# How do you remove arrays containing a string from an object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

Sorry, I am not even quite sure how to phrase my question.

I am trying remove personal registrant information from a public JSON API with a strange setup. Example:

```
"posts" : [
  {
  "id": 9658,
  "type": "event",
  "custom_fields" : {
    "registered_person_0_name" : [ "John" ],
    "registered_person_1_name" : [ "Doe" ]
  }
```

If it helps, this is the `var_dump`:

```
["custom_fields"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6601 (45) {
    ["registered_person_0_name"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "Beverley"
      }
```

There is an unknown number of registrants depending on the event, and each field increments as demonstrated. I figured I would `unset()` all instances of "registered_person," but I am stumped.

If given `$posts`, I feel like I could do something like:

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
  unset( $post->custom_fields->all_the_registered_persons_fields_that_match)
}
```

But I can't quite figure it out. I have attempted typecasting the `custom_fields` object as an array and using `in_array`, then `unset`, but that doesn't seem to work.

I appreciate any pointers. Let me know if I can offer further information.

Comment: That sure is a badly organised data structure

Comment: Do you want to remove just the `registered_person_0_name, registered_person_1_name.....` or the whole `custom_fields`

Comment: It sure is :/ @RiggsFolly. I want to remove `registered_person_#_name` ... but leave the custom fields in tact. FWIW it's an old WordPress JSON API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the property variables and unset them if they match the pattern.

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $custom_fields = $post->custom_fields;
    foreach (get_object_vars($custom_fields) AS $name => $val) {
        if (preg_match('/^registered_person_\d+_name$/', $name)) {
            unset($custom_fields->{$name});
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the optional argument to `json_decode()` so that it returns associative arrays rather than objects. Then you can just use `foreach` on the array.

```
foreach ($posts as &$post) {
    $custom_fields = &$post['custom_fields'];
    foreach ($custom_fields AS $name => $val) {
        if (preg_match('/^registered_person_\d+_name$/', $name)) {
            unset($custom_fields[$name]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in this case you have to use reference variables, because assigning arrays normally makes copies.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. I think I had gotten close to this but `get_object_vars` was totally key. I appreciate it!

Comment: You could also use the option to `json_encode` to return arrays instead of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array with the fields you want removed, you can use `->{$propName}` to achieve this. `->{$someVar}` allows you to dynamically access properties of an object.

For example:

```
$field1 = "name";
echo($object->{$field}) // will echo the name property
```

In your case:

```
$sensibleFields = ['creditCardNumber', 'socialSecurityNumber'];
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    foreach ($sensibleFields as $fieldName) {
        unset($post->{$fieldName});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cristik. I had sort of distantly seen `->{$someVar}` before but didn't understand its use.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `json_decode($the_api_data, true)` to get the results array style instead of object style, then you can use `array_filter` to remove the unwanted keys.

```
foreach ($posts as &$post) {  // need to use a reference here for this to work
    $post['custom_fields'] = array_filter($post['custom_fields'], function($key){
        return 'registered_person_' != substr($key, 0, 18);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
```